# What's the adjective word for "full of resource, lots of sample"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I was wondering if there are any adjective for the following:

> "full of resource that I can refer from"

example conversation:

> Person A: I'm not sure which computer language I should start learning. What do you think? `A` or `B`?
>
> Person B: You should go with `B`. Because `B` is more xxxxful.
>
> (= B language has much more resouces/references that you can learn
>   from)

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "full of resource"... `rich`? `complex`? `more classes available`? `more widely used`?

Comment: more references available, more documents available, more books available, more experts exist around you so that you can just ask around

Comment: Perhaps `popular`, `widely used`, `prominent`, `conventional`, `accepted`.  E.G., `Rather than using Forth, you'd find C++ more conventional and popular.`

Answer (score 2):

> Person A: I'm not sure which computer language I should start learning. What do you think? A or B?
>
> Person B: You should go with B, because there is **a larger body of literature** dedicated to it. Because there are more **[instructional resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instructional_materials)** associated with it. Because it has a richer **online expert community** that you can turn to for help.

Another possible option is **well-documented**, but that would not include web forums and Q&A communities.

Answer (score 0):

## accessible

I would say accessible, because accessible means you can easily learn it or get help for it. Something that is accessible is within reach and therefore there are probably a lot of resources for it.

Definition: [accessible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accessible)

You can also say that the resources themselves are readily accessible, but the meaning is still pretty much the same.

Comment: the question is not about being easy...

Comment: Can I say like `accessible resources`?  > You should go with B.  Because B has more accessible resources